# Rotate label by formula and attribute

Tags: geoserver, sld

I have a point layer with a field/attibute called `trikt` or `srikt` which I need to use to rotate labels.

The labels should be rotated by the formula `MOD(-trikt/360)` (remainder of -trikt/360)
So I try using [IEEERemainder](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/filter/function_reference.html) function:

```
...
       <PointPlacement>
         <Rotation>
           <ogc:function name="IEEERemainder">
             <ogc:mul>
               <ogc:PropertyName>trikt</ogc:PropertyName>
               <ogc:Literal>-1</ogc:Literal>
             </ogc:mul>
             <ogc:Literal>360</ogc:Literal>
         </ogc:function>
         </Rotation>
       </PointPlacement>
...
```

Which cant be right because:

```
line 1272: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element '{"http://www.opengis.net/ogc":function}'. One of '{"http://www.opengis.net/ogc":expression}' is expected.
```

(As a workaround I add a new field in QGIS and calculate using python: `-1*f['trikt']%360`, then rotate by this. Would be nice to be able to skip this step.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function is introduced by name, so:

```
          <Rotation>
            <ogc:Function name="IEEERemainder">
              <ogc:Mul>
                <ogc:PropertyName>MALE</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>-1</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:Mul>
              <ogc:Literal>360</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:Function>
          </Rotation>
```

Note also that all the elements have capital letters.